# DistinctCount for relatedtable with additional filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

In powerBi, a column is created with below formula, and it is working good.

activedays = COUNTAX(RELATEDTABLE(ActivesInactiveData),ActivesInactiveData[Surface Date])

However, I want to add a filter some thing like

ActivesInactiveData[Topic]<> null

Could you please advice on how to do so, most of the examples on web are using on relatedtable etc -  where relation is already build, could you please advice/direct to me what I could find an example of adding filter to relatedtable or filter data from a unrelated table based on field like ID column etc.

Here there is a relation user ID in current table has more than 1 rows in ActivesInactiveData table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ActiveDays = COUNTAX(
                 FILTER(
                    RELATEDTABLE(ActivesInactiveData),
                    ISBLANK(ActivesInactiveData[Topic]) <> FALSE
                    ),
                 ActivesInactiveData[Surface Date]
                 )
```

Please let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Do not have the access of now - will get back in 2-3 days.  Thank you for the help.